# Is there any downside to specifying a very long font stack?

Tags: css

This is what I have:

```
body {
    font-family: Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype",
                 "Frutiger LT Std", Univers, Calibri, "Myriad Pro",
                 Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans",
                 "Nimbus Sans L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,
                 sans-serif;
}
```

That's a whopping 14 fonts! Does using long font stacks like this one have a significant effect on page load time or performance, or is it always a good idea to include as many fonts as needed?

Comment: why would you need it? common design practice is to specify main font and one or two fallbacks for different platforms.

Comment: Whoa! You use those many fonts on the website?

Comment: Are you going to test all of these fonts, to see whether they render well?

Comment: @RobW I did test most of them actually, but I haven't been able to test Univers and the Linux ones. Univers might be redundant.

Comment: Have look at using `@font-face` instead of specifying all those fonts

Comment: I've seen the use of long font stacks advocated here: http://www.sitepoint.com/eight-definitive-font-stacks-3/ to make use of the best possible font(s) available on each platform.

Comment: I deleted my answer because... I don't really like it.

Comment: @AlexLittlejohn Good point, but since my concern is mainly performance, wouldn't loading an external font using `@font-face` increase my load time far more than having a long font stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly, the font stack seems to be from here: http://www.sitepoint.com/eight-definitive-font-stacks-2/ (modified to remove Gill Sans, which makes sense because that font really doesn't fit this group).

It's overkill in a sense (unless you just really, *really* hate Arial), but knowing a lot of these fonts, I can see the logical assumptions the creator had in mind (not to say that I would do this). Frutiger and Univers are very uncommon, but are nice designer fonts. Calibri is a font shipped since Office 2007 and Myriad Pro has been shipped with Acrobat Reader for ages, so you're covered on Windows machines. There are three Linux fonts (DejaVu Sans, Liberation Sans, Nimbus Sans) to cover your bases there. As I mentioned, Gill Sans was eliminated here, but that font ships with Macs. So does Helvetica Neue.

So, to share in the consensus, it's probably not hurting anything, but unless you want to test it extensively, all you're doing is adding page weight and a lot of unknown variables to your design.

Comment: Good answer, though I thought Myriad [Pro] was primarily a Mac font? I assumed that older Mac and Windows machines would fall back on Helvetica and Arial respectively.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Need more caffeine. Myriad is a Mac font. Myriad Pro is an OpenType font that shipped with Acrobat Reader, so it's installed on lots of Windows machines by default (since that often comes with Windows machines). I guess I just always assumed it was a Microsoft font. I've fixed the post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I say it is overkill unless you plan to break it down like I do:

```
/* Web Safe Font Stacks */
.head {font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',serif}
.para {font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif}
.mono {font-family:'Courier New',Courier,monospace}
.fant {font-family: Papyrus,Impact,fantasy}
.curs {font-family:'Apple Chancery','Lucida Calligraphy',cursive}
```

You are welcome to use this example code in your CSS.